# Sorting Algorithm contained in an executable file is command terminated by Signal 11?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, signals

I have an executable file with a sorting algorithm (that I don't know), and my lab is basically to try and figure out the sorting algorithm by inputting in different cases and testing it's complexity/stability.

I tested it on a random list with 500 000 lines, and it worked fine (0.17 seconds to sort 500 000 lines of random data). However, I tried to input in an ordered list of 200 000 lines and this is what the terminal gives me:

```
$ ./gen 180000 A | /usr/bin/time --format="%U seconds" ./sortB > /dev/null
Command terminated by signal 11
32.38 seconds
```

Why is the program doing this? If I recall correctly signall 11 means a segmentation fault right? So it's trying to access memory that's not there? The algorithm worked fine on 500 000 lines of random list, and at 170 000 lines of an ordered list it takes 29.48 seconds to execute (at 180 000 it gave me a signall 11). As I said I can't access the code, and it's an execute only file, but I can't think of why any sorting algorithm would have this problem?

Comment: The algorithm is definitely `quick sort` and is causing `segmentation fault (signal-11)` due to `(recursion) stack overflow`..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. Signal 11 is signal for Segmentation Fault. The sorting executable is trying to access the memory which is not allocated or not permissible for the program to access or the memory does not exists (NULL memory pointer or Garbage pointer).

This might come because the sorting executable is using system stack to perform it's operation (this is common when sorting algorithm is implemented recursively). If the array to be sorted is very long, the system stack may be exhausted.

Try to increase the system stack memory and check.
There are commands/methods to increase the system stack memory size in Linux.

I hope this will help.
Good luck.

Comment: ah, okay i see. so the reason it wouldn't have happened with a random sort, but happened with an ordered sort, is because the ordered sort would require more recursive calls to reach the base case of the function right? (which would mean the algorithm is likely quick sort or the likes... hmmm). thank you!